# mySQL: Query to get all rows every 22nd of previous month

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a requirements to select all rows the startdate should be every 22nd of previous and the enddate will  be every 21st of the current month.

For example, if the current month is October, I want to return all rows that start in September 22 and the end date will be October 22. I have a date column name Transaction_date.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from your_table
where Transaction_date >= CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-22 06:00:00') as DATE) - interval 1 month
  and Transaction_date < CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-22 06:00:00') as DATE)
```

Comment: How can I add timestamp in where condition both should be 6:00am